# How do I set a time zone for a JavaScript date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, timezone

I'm trying to do a countdown timer in JavaScript, using [countdown](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/), but I want the Date object to be relative to a particular time zone.

How can I make sure that my countdown is relative to a specific time/date in a specific time zone?

Comment: depends on source and type of initial date value. Please expand on use case

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/6016329/

Comment: Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/GEpaH/

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-javascript-date-to-a-particular-timezone

Comment: You need to add momentJS library along with this. Check this example of plugin: http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/examples/timezone-aware.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the example of countdown plugin (http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/examples/timezone-aware.html), you need to add MomentJS library to set Date object relative to a particular time zone.

HTML:

```
<div id="clock"></div>
```

JS:

```
var nextYear = moment.tz("2015-08-22 00:00", "America/Sao_Paulo");

$('#clock').countdown(nextYear.toDate(), function(event) {
    $(this).html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kbk798py/